# hyperledger-fabric fabcar example : Container ... is not running

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

### Problem

I'm following this tutorial on official document:

https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html

but stuck in 'launch the network' (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html#launch-the-network)

`./startFabric.sh javascript` returns following error message

```
Error response from daemon: Container 8d4a67101bafc10453ab0a6c7d4afda63edc686ca157f8279ed1ebd11145b25a is not running
```

### Environment

Below is my environment:

OS: Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS 
DOCKER: Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a 
DOCKER-COMPOSE: docker-compose version 1.18.0, build 8dd22a9 
GO: go version go1.12.4 linux/amd64 
NPM: 3.5.2 
NODE: v8.10.0 
Python 2.7.15rc1

/etc/profile:

```
...
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/go/bin
export PATH=/home/sw/fabric/fabric-samples/bin:$PATH
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
```

(PATH variable, GOPATH SET) 
(my $HOME/go directory is empty)

also my ubuntu user is registered to sudo group and also docker group

```
$ groups
... ... ... sudo ... ... docker
```

(I hid the rest)

below is the output when I try to start fabric

```
$ ./startFabric.sh javascript 

# don't rewrite paths for Windows Git Bash users
export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml down
Removing peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Removing couchdb                ... done
Removing ca.example.com         ... done
Removing orderer.example.com    ... done
Removing network net_basic

docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml up -d ca.example.com orderer.example.com peer0.org1.example.com couchdb
Creating couchdb ... done
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... done
Creating orderer.example.com ... 
Creating couchdb ... 
Creating peer0.org1.example.com ... 
docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                        COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS                                            NAMES
90b396af1160        hyperledger/fabric-peer      "peer node start"        1 second ago        Up Less than a second     0.0.0.0:7051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:7053->7053/tcp   peer0.org1.example.com
a0038f19943f        hyperledger/fabric-ca        "sh -c 'fabric-ca-se…"   5 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds              0.0.0.0:7054->7054/tcp                           ca.example.com
77a56465104c        hyperledger/fabric-couchdb   "tini -- /docker-ent…"   5 seconds ago       Up 1 second               4369/tcp, 9100/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5984->5984/tcp       couchdb
7ed9d7dbf17f        hyperledger/fabric-orderer   "orderer"                5 seconds ago       Up 3 seconds              0.0.0.0:7050->7050/tcp                           orderer.example.com
a4397f663fdd        tensorflow/tensorflow        "/run_jupyter.sh --a…"   6 months ago        Exited (0) 6 months ago                                                    jolly_vaughan

# wait for Hyperledger Fabric to start
# incase of errors when running later commands, issue export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=<larger number>
export FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT=10
#echo ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}
sleep ${FABRIC_START_TIMEOUT}

# Create the channel
docker exec -e "CORE_PEER_LOCALMSPID=Org1MSP" -e "CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/msp/users/Admin@org1.example.com/msp" peer0.org1.example.com peer channel create -o orderer.example.com:7050 -c mychannel -f /etc/hyperledger/configtx/channel.tx
Error response from daemon: Container 90b396af1160b6c7e3a35ec41806b428c299f598208dc77c4194ee1fa76a351a is not running
```

seemed like hyperledger/fabric-peer Image is not starting.
So I check the docker log

```
$ docker logs 90b396
2019-04-24 05:31:04.584 UTC [nodeCmd] serve -> INFO 001 Starting peer:
 Version: 1.4.1
 Commit SHA: 87074a7
 Go version: go1.11.5
 OS/Arch: linux/amd64
 Chaincode:
  Base Image Version: 0.4.15
  Base Docker Namespace: hyperledger
  Base Docker Label: org.hyperledger.fabric
  Docker Namespace: hyperledger
2019-04-24 05:31:04.585 UTC [ledgermgmt] initialize -> INFO 002 Initializing ledger mgmt
2019-04-24 05:31:04.585 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 003 Initializing ledger provider
2019-04-24 05:31:04.873 UTC [kvledger] NewProvider -> INFO 004 ledger provider Initialized
2019-04-24 05:31:05.002 UTC [couchdb] handleRequest -> WARN 005 Retrying couchdb request in 125ms. Attempt:1  Error:Get http://couchdb:5984/: dial tcp 172.18.0.3:5984: connect: connection refused
fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x63 pc=0x7f12f457d259]

runtime stack:
runtime.throw(0x1272c18, 0x2a)
    /opt/go/src/runtime/panic.go:608 +0x72
runtime.sigpanic()
    /opt/go/src/runtime/signal_unix.go:374 +0x2f2

goroutine 91 [syscall]:
runtime.cgocall(0xe455e0, 0xc0001a9e00, 0x29)
    /opt/go/src/runtime/cgocall.go:128 +0x5e fp=0xc0001a9dc8 sp=0xc0001a9d90 pc=0x4039ee
net._C2func_getaddrinfo(0xc0004580c0, 0x0, 0xc0001d2240, 0xc00079e140, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    _cgo_gotypes.go:91 +0x55 fp=0xc0001a9e00 sp=0xc0001a9dc8 pc=0x616c85
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME.func1(0xc0004580c0, 0x0, 0xc0001d2240, 0xc00079e140, 0x8, 0x8, 0xc0007b0370)
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:149 +0x131 fp=0xc0001a9e48 sp=0xc0001a9e00 pc=0x61c3b1
net.cgoLookupIPCNAME(0xc0004580b0, 0x7, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:149 +0x153 fp=0xc0001a9f38 sp=0xc0001a9e48 pc=0x618243
net.cgoIPLookup(0xc0005144e0, 0xc0004580b0, 0x7)
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:201 +0x4d fp=0xc0001a9fc8 sp=0xc0001a9f38 pc=0x6188fd
runtime.goexit()
    /opt/go/src/runtime/asm_amd64.s:1333 +0x1 fp=0xc0001a9fd0 sp=0xc0001a9fc8 pc=0x45de51
created by net.cgoLookupIP
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:211 +0xad

goroutine 1 [select]:
net/http.(*Transport).getConn(0xc0004c9680, 0xc0001d2120, 0x0, 0xc000674000, 0x4, 0xc0004580b0, 0xc, 0x0, 0x0, 0x20)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1004 +0x58e
net/http.(*Transport).roundTrip(0xc0004c9680, 0xc000798200, 0xc0001d20f0, 0xc000458098, 0xc0004580a0)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/transport.go:451 +0x690
net/http.(*Transport).RoundTrip(0xc0004c9680, 0xc000798200, 0xc0004c9680, 0xbf281b0f07aea3df, 0x851175c92)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/roundtrip.go:17 +0x35
net/http.send(0xc000798000, 0x139e6e0, 0xc0004c9680, 0xbf281b0f07aea3df, 0x851175c92, 0x1fa1740, 0xc00079e110, 0xbf281b0f07aea3df, 0xc0004aab48, 0x1)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/client.go:250 +0x14b
net/http.(*Client).send(0xc00066f560, 0xc000798000, 0xbf281b0f07aea3df, 0x851175c92, 0x1fa1740, 0xc00079e110, 0x0, 0x1, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/client.go:174 +0xfa
net/http.(*Client).do(0xc00066f560, 0xc000798000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/client.go:641 +0x2a8
net/http.(*Client).Do(0xc00066f560, 0xc000798000, 0x10, 0xc0004aae40, 0x1)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/client.go:509 +0x35
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/util/couchdb.(*CouchInstance).handleRequest(0xc00067f740, 0x13b7a20, 0xc000046090, 0x123cf31, 0x3, 0x0, 0x0, 0x124c88f, 0x11, 0xc000128a80, ...)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/util/couchdb/couchdb.go:1752 +0x64e
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/util/couchdb.(*CouchInstance).VerifyCouchConfig(0xc00067f740, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/util/couchdb/couchdb.go:410 +0x345
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/util/couchdb.CreateCouchInstance(0xc0000440af, 0xc, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x3, 0xc, 0x826299e00, 0xc000042000, ...)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/util/couchdb/couchdbutil.go:58 +0x29e
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/txmgmt/statedb/statecouchdb.NewVersionedDBProvider(0x13b0260, 0x1fc5e60, 0xb972cb, 0x10d80c0, 0xc000670018)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/txmgmt/statedb/statecouchdb/statecouchdb.go:46 +0xe4
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/txmgmt/privacyenabledstate.NewCommonStorageDBProvider(0x13a2ce0, 0xc000670018, 0x13b0260, 0x1fc5e60, 0x139cac0, 0xc0007b4c00, 0x2, 0x4, 0x0, 0xc000128800)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/txmgmt/privacyenabledstate/common_storage_db.go:48 +0x48
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger.(*Provider).Initialize(0xc000128800, 0xc00062fda0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/kvledger/kv_ledger_provider.go:88 +0x25e
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.initialize(0xc00046ed70)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt/ledger_mgmt.go:73 +0x4b4
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.Initialize.func1()
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt/ledger_mgmt.go:53 +0x2a
sync.(*Once).Do(0x1fc5f38, 0xc0004794e0)
    /opt/go/src/sync/once.go:44 +0xb3
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt.Initialize(0xc00046ed70)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/ledger/ledgermgmt/ledger_mgmt.go:52 +0x55
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node.serve(0x1fc5e60, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node/start.go:176 +0x5bd
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node.glob..func1(0x1eb3b00, 0x1fc5e60, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/node/start.go:121 +0x9c
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute(0x1eb3b00, 0x1fc5e60, 0x0, 0x0, 0x1eb3b00, 0x1fc5e60)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:762 +0x473
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC(0x1eb4220, 0x8, 0x0, 0x1eb33e0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:852 +0x2fd
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute(0x1eb4220, 0xc0004a7f40, 0x1)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/spf13/cobra/command.go:800 +0x2b
main.main()
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/main.go:53 +0x2f7

goroutine 8 [syscall]:
os/signal.signal_recv(0x0)
    /opt/go/src/runtime/sigqueue.go:139 +0x9c
os/signal.loop()
    /opt/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:23 +0x22
created by os/signal.init.0
    /opt/go/src/os/signal/signal_unix.go:29 +0x41

goroutine 21 [IO wait]:
internal/poll.runtime_pollWait(0x7f12f5994f00, 0x72, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/runtime/netpoll.go:173 +0x66
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).wait(0xc00045c198, 0x72, 0xc000082000, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:85 +0x9a
internal/poll.(*pollDesc).waitRead(0xc00045c198, 0xffffffffffffff00, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/internal/poll/fd_poll_runtime.go:90 +0x3d
internal/poll.(*FD).Accept(0xc00045c180, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/internal/poll/fd_unix.go:384 +0x1a0
net.(*netFD).accept(0xc00045c180, 0x7f12fa405000, 0x0, 0xc000058eb0)
    /opt/go/src/net/fd_unix.go:238 +0x42
net.(*TCPListener).accept(0xc00079e690, 0xc000058eb8, 0x40d1d8, 0x30)
    /opt/go/src/net/tcpsock_posix.go:139 +0x2e
net.(*TCPListener).Accept(0xc00079e690, 0x1174aa0, 0xc0001d60c0, 0x1074180, 0x1ea5270)
    /opt/go/src/net/tcpsock.go:260 +0x47
net/http.(*Server).Serve(0xc000665a00, 0x13b6a20, 0xc00079e690, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/server.go:2826 +0x22f
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations.(*System).Start
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/core/operations/system.go:121 +0x1a3

goroutine 22 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc0001f8a80)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x12a
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x177

goroutine 10 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc0000b31e0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0xd3
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x40c

goroutine 11 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc0000b31e0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:101 +0xe7
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:143 +0x42e

goroutine 12 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc0000b31e0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:834 +0x331
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x58c

goroutine 13 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc0000b31e0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:762 +0x12e
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x5ae

goroutine 14 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc0001f82a0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x12a
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x177

goroutine 15 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc0000b3380)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0xd3
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x40c

goroutine 16 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc0000b3380)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:101 +0xe7
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:143 +0x42e

goroutine 66 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc0000b3380)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:834 +0x331
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x58c

goroutine 67 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc0000b3380)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:762 +0x12e
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x5ae

goroutine 68 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc0007a40e0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x12a
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x177

goroutine 69 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc0000b3520)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0xd3
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x40c

goroutine 70 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc0000b3520)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:101 +0xe7
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:143 +0x42e

goroutine 71 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc0000b3520)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:834 +0x331
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x58c

goroutine 72 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc0000b3520)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:762 +0x12e
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x5ae

goroutine 73 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc0007a42a0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x12a
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x177

goroutine 74 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc0000b36c0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0xd3
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x40c

goroutine 75 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc0000b36c0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:101 +0xe7
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:143 +0x42e

goroutine 76 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc0000b36c0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:834 +0x331
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x58c

goroutine 77 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc0000b36c0)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:762 +0x12e
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x5ae

goroutine 78 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc0007a4460)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x12a
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x177

goroutine 79 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc0000b3860)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0xd3
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x40c

goroutine 80 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc0000b3860)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:101 +0xe7
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:143 +0x42e

goroutine 81 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc0000b3860)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:834 +0x331
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x58c

goroutine 82 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc0000b3860)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:762 +0x12e
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x5ae

goroutine 83 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.(*BufferPool).drain(0xc0007a4620)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:206 +0x12a
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util.NewBufferPool
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/util/buffer_pool.go:237 +0x177

goroutine 36 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).compactionError(0xc0000b3a00)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:90 +0xd3
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:142 +0x40c

goroutine 37 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mpoolDrain(0xc0000b3a00)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_state.go:101 +0xe7
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:143 +0x42e

goroutine 38 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).tCompaction(0xc0000b3a00)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:834 +0x331
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:149 +0x58c

goroutine 39 [select]:
github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.(*DB).mCompaction(0xc0000b3a00)
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db_compaction.go:762 +0x12e
created by github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb.openDB
    /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/vendor/github.com/syndtr/goleveldb/leveldb/db.go:150 +0x5ae

goroutine 89 [select]:
net.(*Resolver).LookupIPAddr(0x1fa0d00, 0x13b7a20, 0xc000046090, 0xc0004580b0, 0x7, 0xc0004580b8, 0x4, 0x1760, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/lookup.go:227 +0x55f
net.(*Resolver).internetAddrList(0x1fa0d00, 0x13b7a20, 0xc000046090, 0x123d330, 0x3, 0xc0004580b0, 0xc, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/go/src/net/ipsock.go:279 +0x614
net.(*Resolver).resolveAddrList(0x1fa0d00, 0x13b7a20, 0xc000046090, 0x123da6a, 0x4, 0x123d330, 0x3, 0xc0004580b0, 0xc, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/go/src/net/dial.go:202 +0x4fb
net.(*Dialer).DialContext(0x1fa18c0, 0x13b7a20, 0xc000046090, 0x123d330, 0x3, 0xc0004580b0, 0xc, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/go/src/net/dial.go:384 +0x201
net/http.(*Transport).dial(0xc0004c9680, 0x13b7a20, 0xc000046090, 0x123d330, 0x3, 0xc0004580b0, 0xc, 0xc00062e700, 0xc0005b9db8, 0xc0005b9c00, ...)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/transport.go:925 +0x17f
net/http.(*Transport).dialConn(0xc0004c9680, 0x13b7a20, 0xc000046090, 0x0, 0xc000674000, 0x4, 0xc0004580b0, 0xc, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/transport.go:1240 +0x313
net/http.(*Transport).getConn.func4(0xc0004c9680, 0x13b7a20, 0xc000046090, 0xc0001d2150, 0xc0004684e0)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/transport.go:999 +0x6e
created by net/http.(*Transport).getConn
    /opt/go/src/net/http/transport.go:998 +0x3d7

goroutine 90 [select]:
net.cgoLookupIP(0x13b79e0, 0xc00049e140, 0xc0004580b0, 0x7, 0x0, 0xc000797bc0, 0x1069d40, 0xc000520030, 0x1010720, 0xc0007b1350)
    /opt/go/src/net/cgo_unix.go:212 +0x17b
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP(0x1fa0d00, 0x13b79e0, 0xc00049e140, 0xc0004580b0, 0x7, 0x0, 0xc000462d80, 0xc0006779c0, 0xc000797fa0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/lookup_unix.go:95 +0x166
net.(*Resolver).lookupIP-fm(0x13b79e0, 0xc00049e140, 0xc0004580b0, 0x7, 0x42be22, 0xc000000008, 0xc0006779c0, 0xc0007b0370, 0xc0001a9ea0)
    /opt/go/src/net/lookup.go:207 +0x56
net.glob..func1(0x13b79e0, 0xc00049e140, 0xc000796350, 0xc0004580b0, 0x7, 0xc000796a70, 0x1069d40, 0xc00019d740, 0x1069d40, 0xc0007a3560)
    /opt/go/src/net/hook.go:19 +0x52
net.(*Resolver).LookupIPAddr.func1(0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /opt/go/src/net/lookup.go:221 +0xd8
internal/singleflight.(*Group).doCall(0x1fa0d10, 0xc000012230, 0xc0004580b0, 0x7, 0xc0001d21e0)
    /opt/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:95 +0x2e
created by internal/singleflight.(*Group).DoChan
    /opt/go/src/internal/singleflight/singleflight.go:88 +0x2a0

goroutine 88 [select]:
net/http.setRequestCancel.func3(0x0, 0xc0001d20f0, 0xc0000121e0, 0xc000458098, 0xc000468480)
    /opt/go/src/net/http/client.go:321 +0xcf
created by net/http.setRequestCancel
    /opt/go/src/net/http/client.go:320 +0x24e
```

looked like below is the main cause.

```
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x63 pc=0x7f12f457d259]
```

I have tried
- deleting and reinstalling
- shutting down pre-exist network (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.4/write_first_app.html#set-up-the-blockchain-network)

but the problem remained the same.

So these are all I've got.
Can someone please let me know what is the problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

You can try to set the following environment variable in the peer: GODEBUG=netdns=go